# SetTImeout for ondrop function?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a function called `format()` that I would like to call after `ondrop`, but I need it to wait for 1 second before firing. I am new to JavaScript. How would I write that?

```
ondrop="setTimeout(format, 1000);"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set timeout works by supplying two parameters, the function to call and the delay to wait,

```
setTimeout(format, 1000);
```

or

```
setTimeout(function(){
  //any other code you made need to run
  format()
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
obj.ondrop = function() {
    setTimeout(format, 1000);
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick and fast response.

Answer (score 0):

```
ondrop = setTimeout(function(){
    format();
}, 1000)
```

Comment: This won't work - a `setTimeout` call returns an integer, so you're assigning an integer to `ondrop`, not a function.